# What is meant by "INPUT_RECORDS_PROCESSED" for (Hive-llap)+(HDFS-ORC) in Ambari

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I have run the (Hive+LLAP) for (HDFS-ORC) in Ambari server and it run successful. In "GraphView", for each "Map" it show "INPUT_RECORDS_PROCESSED" for tasks.

It shows less number of input records processed than output records.

What is meant by "INPUT_RECORDS_PROCESSED"?